# How to install something in ClearLinux without a bundle?

Tags: docker, clear-linux

Let's say I want to install something in Clear Linux that there isn't a bundle for. E.g. Postgres or MongoDB.

What is the official way to do this?

Or is it perhaps then Clear Linux is not the OS to use?

Btw. This post ought to have a clearlinux tag, but I don't have the reputation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling is a never fail solution, you just need to install `user-basic-dev` bundle, with that you should be more than able to compile any software you like.